# opening a .txt file

Tags: python, file, input

first, i'd like to mention that im using python via visual studio. not sure if this information will
be relevant but this is my first time using file input so i'm not sure

basically, i have a .txt file located in the same location as my .py file. however, when i go to access it, i get an error 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

is there a way to make it work or a different IDE i should use?

I tried reading a .txt file from the same location as my .py file. however, i keep getting the error 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Comment: Share the code you're using along with the screenshot of the directory structure.

Comment: the location of your `.py` file is *completely irrelevant*. What is important is the apth you passed to `open`, and if it is a relative path, the working directory.

Comment: If the only knowledge you have is the path of your file relative to your .py file, then the location of the .py file surely is a completely relevant piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that the script might not be running from the same path where your python script is and most probably your are not specifying the exact path of the file.

If your file is located in the same directory where your python sript is you can use the `pathlib` library this way to get your script to work:

```py
import pathlib

# Some custom code

# find your current script path
current_script_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

my_file_name = "my_file_name.txt"

# Specify the file path relative to your script's path
my_file_path = current_script_path / my_file_name

with open(my_file_path, "r+") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: thanks, that worked in printing the contents of my text file. however, i have a module for testing which still isnt working due to the same error. is there any way to save a file to the exact directory as the script?

Comment: You should give more context on your particular implementation... I tried this same code and tested it using `pytest` from a script within a `test/` directory and it worked.